# Minecraft server hosting not working on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, macos, hosting, server-administration

I set up a Minecraft server on my Mac (macOS Big Sur 11.1) using Mojang's provided server jar file (https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server). It worked when I joined from the LAN with the IP `localhost` as well as the IP address the computer used to connect to the internet (I am connecting to the internet with iPhone USB hotspot as I cannot get WiFi where I live). However when other people tried to join they got this error message:

`Failed to connect to the server`

`io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:`

This happened even when I disabled my firewall and allowed all incoming connections.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you forwarded your ports? Try connecting using your public IP. Does it work?

Comment: are you trying to connect via your local ip address over wan? please watch a tutorial about making a minecraft server instead of doing it on your own if you dont know how to do it.

Comment: First of all, `localhost` does not go over LAN, because it never leaves your computer. Second, when you say "*the IP address the computer used to connect to the internet*", are you connecting to your mac using a different computer connected to a different network? If so, other people should have no issues connecting to your mac either, unless they didn't configure their client properly.

Comment: I know that this is probably an issue because I am connected to the internet through iPhone hotspot. Therefore I cannot forward ports. Is there any way to make it work with an iPhone hotspot?

Comment: there is no way to port forward hotspot, instead connect to your wifi router